# Is there a gitkraken feature which shows how much commits behind | ahead a branch is compared to another branch?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I am a noob at gitkraken (not at git) and I am searching for a feature which compares a branch regarding "number of commits behind | ahead". Is there any way to do this:
The similar git command is:

```
git rev-list --left-right --count branchA...branchB
```

Microsoft's Azure DevOps also supports this feature in the WebUI (always compares it to master):

[image]

Comment: Not answering your question, but may be useful anyway: You can actually configure the "comparison branch" in Azure DevOps. Set the option in the branch context menu hidden under the `:` context menu thingy.

Comment: @jessehouwing: pretty nice to know, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking to commit in the middle zone you will have a list of everything included in the diff
On Windows it's Ctrl + click

[image: Screenshot of the diff in GitKraken]